# Client Certificate Authentication in .NET (Windows Server)

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have a very weird issue with a Web Application I have deployed.

Relevant Data:

```
Application Server: IIS 7.5
Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1
Framework: ASP.NET
.NET Framework: 4 (4.0.30319)
Application Pool: Integrated
```

I the web application I make use of a service that's authenticated with Client Certificate Authentication. I don't have problems relating to the authentication itself (it is working on my development environment). But I am seeing problems whenever I want to use the service from the server (production) environment.

Here's the relevant portion of the CODE:

```
private void SetupClienteCertificate(HttpWebRequest req)
{
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        var crt = new X509Certificate2(
            txtClientCertificateFile.Text, 
            txtCertificatePassword.Text, 
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet
        );
        req.ClientCertificates.Add(crt);
}
```

The error I am getting is pretty common and self explanatory:

> `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

The **very weird part of it is** that if I run the **exact same code** from a `C#` .Net Windows Forms Desktop Application (with the same .NET 4 framework) I can get the code to communicate with the server.

So my question is: **Why is it working from the Desktop Application and not working from the ASP.NET Web Application?**

Some stuff that I've already made sure of:

1. SSLv3, TLS, TLSv1, TLSv2 are enabled in the registry
2. I am ignoring SSL CERTIFICATE ERRORS (not necessary, but *JUST IN CASE*)
3. Restarted the Application Pool every time I change something configuration wise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the desktop application and the web server application (not the machine running the browser) running on the same machine when one succeeds and the other fails?

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes, they are. Both of them running on the exact same Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 computer.

Comment: @NightOwl888 the only difference is the Desktop App runs under one regular windwos user, and the Web App runs under whatever user is set to run the IIS Server.

Comment: Well, there is a big clue. It is likely some sort of Widows permission issue. Try temporarily setting the IIS user to run as an Administrator to confirm. Also, check the Windows event log on the web server to see if there is any info logged there at the time you tried to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I think I get your problem. **Can you ensure the account under which application pool is running have sufficient privilege to read certificate from certificate
store**.